# Pass entity manager to custom validator

Tags: validation, jpa

I wan to create a custom validator that enable to have unique key across many table when there is inheritance. i need to pass entity manager to this custom validator or validator factory how to do that? 
**EDIT**
I am using EJB(glassfish) with jpa(Eclipse link) and jsr 303.

Comment: yes i am using the bean validation jsr

Comment: are you using Spring?

Comment: nope, EJB . i will edit the question

Comment: I can see that you unaccepted answer, do you still have a problem with injecting `EntityManager` to your validator?

Comment: nope it worked fine, i might have unaccepted it by mistake, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JSR 330 (DI) states:

> The default ConstraintValidatorFactory provided by the Bean Validation
>   provider implementation uses the public no-arg constructor of the
>   ConstraintValidator class. A custom ConstraintValidatorFactory can be
>   provided; for example it may benefit from dependency injection control
>   in constraint implementations. Any constraint implementation relying
>   on ConstraintValidatorFactory behaviors specific to an implementation
>   (dependency injection, no no-arg constructor and so on) are not
>   considered portable, hence great care should be given before walking
>   that path.

So you can either create `ConstraintValidatorFactory` or use manual lookup:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) ctx.lookup("urlTo" + MyClass.class.getName())
```